# cmd.exe and runcbl.exe errors

Tags: cmd

I have a program on my company network that I'm suddenly unable to open.  When I try I get the following errors:

\Bpiserver\accounting\CSSI\lori1
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
Could not find C:\Windows\STATUS.*

another error box pops up on top of that one saying

Windows cannot find 'RUNCBL'.

I have searched the internet in every way I can and have not found one piece of info that relates to this specific problem.

I'm using Windows 7

I have run several antivirus programs and found no problems.

PLEEEEASE help!  I am in HR and cannot run paychecks, etc until I can get into this program.

Answer (score 1):

"RunCBL" may be a COBOL runtime/helper, which would make sense for a payroll app.  It would be like trying to double-click a .doc or .docx file if Windows couldn't find the MS Word executable.
Either the file has been deleted, or your path has changed.  (Right-click My Computer, go to Properties, Advanced, Environment variables.)

The UNC path is a common complaint.  DOS/Windows scripts (.bat or .cmd files) don't like to start in network folders -- unless the network folder is mapped to a DOS-style drive letter.  (In other words, you would have a virtual X: or Z: drive on your PC that pointed to \Bpiserver\accounting or \Bpiserver\accounting\CSSI.)

If you had a drive mapping and that got deleted somehow, that could account for all of these problems.
If you want further assistance you should probably post the contents of \Bpiserver\accounting\CSSI\lori1.cmd

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you do not have access to the network path needed to run that program.

```
UNC path: \\Bpiserver\accounting\CSSI\lori1
```

Also, it may be possible to disable this UNC check:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156276

Comment: Would this be the case even if I am able to access and run other programs on this same server?  My co-workers are able to access this same program with no troubles.

Comment: If the network path exists, then the problem is with this application somehow.  A little digging shows that RUNCBL might be a COBOL command interpreter... and it cannot be found... do you have that installed?  Also, what are you launching... is it a .exe, a .lnk, a script?